# Gmail API send message without using Base64 encode

Tags: google-api, gmail, gmail-api

I am using this interface: 
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send#examples

I was testing API request from the form on the website. It requires raw Base64 encoded string such as:

```
TUlNRS1WZXJzaW9uOiAxLjANClJlY2VpdmVkOiBieSAxMC4xOTQuNjguMjI3IHdpdGggSFRUUDsgV2VkLCAyNCBBdWcgMjAxNiAwMjo1OToxNyAtMDcwMCAoUERUKQ0KRGF0ZTogV2VkLCAyNCBBdWcgMjAxNiAxMTo1OToxNyArMDIwMA0KRGVsaXZlcmVkLVRvOiBrcnVub0B1bGl4dHJhdmVsLmNvbQ0KTWVzc2FnZS1JRDogPENBSzB5QmZZeEgwS1dGbng2TzNfZ3ZNRkxtVlB5RVY9NjdnQW5qRWdPaHIzSGZOTkJCUUBtYWlsLmdtYWlsLmNvbT4NClN1YmplY3Q6IFRoaXMgaXMgYSBzdWJqZWN0DQpGcm9tOiBLcnVub3NsYXYgVUxJWFRyYXZlbCA8a3J1bm9AdWxpeHRyYXZlbC5jb20-DQpUbzogS3J1bm9zbGF2IEJhbm92YWMgPGt1bm9rZGV2QGdtYWlsLmNvbT4NCkNvbnRlbnQtVHlwZTogbXVsdGlwYXJ0L2FsdGVybmF0aXZlOyBib3VuZGFyeT0wNDdkN2JhZTQ5NjRhMmQ3MzAwNTNhY2U1NWUxDQoNCi0tMDQ3ZDdiYWU0OTY0YTJkNzMwMDUzYWNlNTVlMQ0KQ29udGVudC1UeXBlOiB0ZXh0L3BsYWluOyBjaGFyc2V0PVVURi04DQoNClRoaXMgaXMgYSBib2R5DQoNCi0tMDQ3ZDdiYWU0OTY0YTJkNzMwMDUzYWNlNTVlMQ0KQ29udGVudC1UeXBlOiB0ZXh0L2h0bWw7IGNoYXJzZXQ9VVRGLTgNCg0KPGRpdiBkaXI9Imx0ciI-VGhpcyBpcyBhIGJvZHk8YnI-PC9kaXY-DQoNCi0tMDQ3ZDdiYWU0OTY0YTJkNzMwMDUzYWNlNTVlMS0t
```

How do I instead use basic parameters (such as subject, sender, reciver, message body) to send mail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first build the message with headers like`From` and `Subject` as you mentioned, but you have to encode the message before sending it. There is no way around that.

The following is an example in JavaScript, with the use of JQuery:

```
// Base64-encode the mail and make it URL-safe 
// (replace all "+" with "-" and all "/" with "_")
var encodedMessage = btoa([
  "From: sender@gmail.com\r\n",
  "To: reciever@gmail.com\r\n",
  "Subject: Subject of the message\r\n\r\n",

  "This is the text of the message"
].join("")).replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_');

$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send?access_token={access_token}",
  contentType: "application/json",
  data: JSON.stringify({           
    raw: encodedMessage
  })
});
```

Comment: But I do not understand why do we need to replace these characters? (`+` to `-`, etc...)

Comment: It's a form of base64 encoding called url safe. It is sometimes needed because some characters can not be transferred safely otherwise. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374753/passing-base64-encoded-strings-in-url) might explain it some.

Comment: May I ask you, is JavaScript code example from https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send#examples legit when used for  Node.js that is executed from the terminal such as `node script.js` ?

Comment: @Kunok Yeah, sure. `gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.send` basically takes care of the `access_token` above, under the hood. It is pretty [difficult to setup](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs), but it works great. I like to get an `access_token` from the [playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/)  with the Gmail scopes and use that like above, instead. It is easier for testing purposes.

Comment: Yeah, I am trying to set this up but I am calling Node script from PHP code and OAuth setup didn't go well for me, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39118733/when-oauth2-google-api-script-is-called-from-other-script-it-is-not-possible-to