# Gmail api send with Postman

Tags: gmail, postman, gmail-api

I am trying to send a mail using gmail API with POSTMAN, using POST Method

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/gmail/v1/users/example@gmail.com/messages/send
```

but I get an error below:

```
{
    "error": {
        "errors": [
            {
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "invalidArgument"
                "message": "Recipient address required"
            }
        ],
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Recipient address required"
    }
}
```

header is already putted Content-type: message/rfc822

I know that this has to be encoded into base64(web_safe), so I translated

```
"From: sender.example@gmail.com\r\n" +
"To: receiver.example@gmail.com\r\n" +
"Subject: Subject Example\r\n" +
"This is content: hope you got it\r\n"
```

I also replaced them to be web_safe

```
 replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_').replace(/=+$/, '');
```

so I got an base64 like below.
so I put raw in body of POST METHOD

```
{
    "raw": "RnJvbTogc2VuZGVyLmV4YW1wbGVAZ21haWwuY29tDQpUbzogcmVjZWl2ZXIuZXhhbXBsZUBnbWFpbC5jb20NClN1YmplY3Q6IFN1YmplY3QgRXhhbXBsZQ0KVGhpcyBpcyBjb250ZW50OiBob3BlIHlvdSBnb3QgaXQNCg"
}
```

I used 'try this api' on google developers' site, and  I could send it.
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send

But with POSTMAN, I cannot.

Any help please?

Comment: Hiya,

This link should help !

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24460422/how-to-send-a-message-successfully-using-the-new-gmail-rest-api

Comment: Thanks @WilfredClement , but not really. Cause I think I already satisfy all the conditions. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

**This mean, data format is incorrect**. You should try below method which perfectly worked for me.

I use below format.

```
From: <FROM@gmail.com>
To: <TO@gmail.com>
Subject: Test Email

Test
```

For testing purpose, I used https://ostermiller.org/calc/encode.html to 64encode above text message. So I will get encoded string as below

```
IEZyb206IDxGUk9NQGdtYWlsLmNvbT4KICAgIFRvOiA8VE9AZ21haWwuY29tPgogICAgU3ViamVjdDogVGVzdCBFbWFpbAogICAgCiAgICBUZXN0
```

Now in postman,

Gmail Rest API URL you have to use `https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/<YOUR@gmail.com>/messages/send`

Content type should be json because you send json format in message body.

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

In body

```
{
    "raw": "IEZyb206IDxGUk9NQGdtYWlsLmNvbT4KICAgIFRvOiA8VE9AZ21haWwuY29tPgogICAgU3ViamVjdDogVGVzdCBFbWFpbAogICAgCiAgICBUZXN0"
}
```

---

### So finally postman looks like as below.

[image]

[image]

Once you send a request to API, You  will receive response looks like this

```
{
    "id": "172016110a227c19",
    "threadId": "172016110a227c19",
    "labelIds": [
        "UNREAD",
        "SENT",
        "INBOX"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should set the `Content-type` header to `application/json`. Also, don't forget to add the `Authorization` header.

Comment: Thank you, but I already did all.
if I set content-type to application/json, it doesn't work. it has to be a rfc822.
and I added Authorization already. I guess it's just an argument problem.
Anyway thanks.

Comment: The way i use it: if you want to set content type to rfc822, you dont need to convert the request in Base64url, you just send the formated email in the body of the request. For more examples, check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24908700/mail-attachment-wrong-media-type-gmail-api

Comment: Hey Thank you! Unbelievable. Cause I also saw this just yesterday!! and I came here to update and you already did! Thank you So much!! Just may I ask you a question? It also says send all the parameters(from, to, subject, ...) without  curly brace. is there any way to use curly brace? if I use it, I got bounce... I am using ipaas now, and it provides {} automatically. thanks

Comment: I don't think that you can format the headers using {}. Instead, you can format using this format: `To: FirstName LastName <address@provider.com>`

Answer (score 0):

[image]

If you want more details please refer below link:
[How to send a message successfully using the new Gmail REST API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24460422/how-to-send-a-message-successfully-using-the-new-gmail-rest-api)

Answer (score 0):

[image: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61507172/2131809]

If you want more details please refer below link: [Gmail API send message without using Base64 encode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39120416/gmail-api-send-message-without-using-base64-encode?rq=1)